# Java: Do changed interfaces call for new package names?

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design, package, bounded-contexts

Due to major refactoring and rearchitecturing of a "bounded context" (Eric Evan's domain-driven design) inside my application, some of that bounded context's *published interfaces* and their methods changed in naming and semantics (*published interface* here meaning that this interface is called from another bounded context).

I'm now in the process of implementing this updated bounded context and I have to decide on the package naming of my changed interfaces.

- Should I keep the old name? `my.company.old.package.name`
- Should I add a version number? `my.company.old.package.name.2`
- ?

In my specific case, due to the updated bounded context being used solely inside my own application, and all other client bounded contexts being few, it is feasible to also change those client bounded contexts to adapt to any new names and semantics.

Probably, generally, there are criteria/metrics/rules of thumb/best practices that could help me decide on the package name. What are yours?

Comment: Why not create interfaces with new names and marking the old ones as deprecated?